# Does a MIDI file's resolution affect it's tempo?

Tags: midi

I have a set of MIDI files whose resolution I need to convert from 96 to 480. The tempo of these MIDI files were set with their resolution at 96. If I convert their resolution to 480, and adjust the note timings to fit the new resolution, do I also need to do some kind of conversion of the BPM to properly denote the timings at the new higher resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolution and Tempo are independent.

Resolution is the number of midi clocks per quarter note.
Tempo is the number of quarter notes per minute.

Resolution is set once in the MIDI file header, 96 is the standard value.
Tempo can be changed multiple times during the playback via the SetTempo events.

Your BPM should not change when you increase the resolution as you described above.

See the official specs at https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://www.midi.org/component/edocman/rp-001-v1-0-standard-midi-files-specification-96-1-4-pdf/fdocument